# Progress update from already running BackgroundTask?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

How can the main app get progress notifications from a background task that is already running when the main app starts ?
I have registered a background task that is triggered with a `SystemTriggerType.TimeZoneChange` (for simplicity). Here's the code:

```
public sealed class Class1:IBackgroundTask
{
    public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        var defferal = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        for (uint i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            taskInstance.Progress = i;
        }
        defferal.Complete();
    }
}
```

The progress is correctly reported in a progress bar.
At the start of the app I re-attache the Completed and Progress events

```
foreach (var i in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
{
   i.Value.Completed += task_Completed;
   i.Value.Progress += task_Progress;
}
```

but I guess the taskInstance isn't updated if the task is already running...

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [background task sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Task-Sample-9209ade9).  It does exactly what your trying to do and it is updating just fine.